# Prevent re-render ReactJS when using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Hello guys ? So i'm developing web with React right now, and i need to make stopwatch timer that will be played when i click the button, so i use setInterval() method. But when i click the button and setInterval() is running, i got this warning from [why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) library, which means to avoid re-rendering. I already use PureComponent but why when setInterval() is running some component still re-render? it makes lag guys, and if i stop setInterval with clearInterval() method the component is stop re-rendering.

[image]

The code just like this:

```
startTimer() {
  // Test
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isSessionStarted: true,
      duration: prevState.duration,
      startedAt: Date.now() - prevState.duration
    }),
    () => {
      this.timer = setInterval(
        () =>
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            duration: Date.now() - prevState.startedAt
          })),
        1000
      );
    }
  );
}

stopTimer() {
  this.setState({ isSessionFinished: true }, () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  });
}
```

Any solution? Thank you before.

Comment: From [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate): `setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.`

Comment: can you also share your render function?

Comment: @apokryfos https://gist.github.com/dafapramudya/6ed368a5cb9d5c3f71012c0bbb862a23

Comment: Assuming that `_getDuration` will return what's in `state.duration` then re-rendering on each tick **is necessary**

Comment: @apokryfos hmm, but it's still re-rendering even though i remove _getDuration method

Comment: It will re-render every time you call `setState` as @nubinub mentioned. However what I'm saying is the way you had built your component that seems to be your intention.

Comment: if you dont want to re-render then I think you can declare duration as a part of your component. You need to convert your component to class.